# PHP readdir is not reading some files

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to loop through a directory to print out the names of the files. However, not all of the files are displayed. I have tried using **clearstatcache** with no effect.

```
    $str = '';
    $ignore = array('.', '..');

    $dh = @opendir( $path );
    if ($dh === FALSE)
    {
        // error
    }

    $file = readdir( $dh );
    while( $file !== FALSE )
    {
        if (in_array($file, $ignore, TRUE)) { break; }
        $str .= $file."\n";
        $file = readdir( $dh );
    }
```

Here's the contents of the directory right now:

```
root.auth  test1.auth  test2.auth  test3.auth  test5.auth
```

However, test5.auth does not appear. If I rename it to test4.auth it does not appear. If I rename it to test6.auth it **does** appear. This is reliable behaviour - I can rename it several times and it still won't show up unless I rename it to test6.auth.

What on earth could be happening?

I'm running Arch Linux (kernel 2.6.26-ARCH) with PHP Version 5.2.6 and Apache/2.2.9 with Suhosin-Patch. My filesystem is ext3 and I'm running fam 2.6.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` keywords messes up your code:
Your loop very likely first encounters the  '.' directory and than breaks out of your while loop.

try replacing it with a `continue` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Continue won't work either, because you will skip the line that reads the next file.

You could get rid of the first `$file = readdir( $dh );` and then do

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {
    if (in_array($file, $ignore, TRUE)) { continue; }
    $str .= $file."\n";
}
```

Comment: Well spotted - can't believe we all missed that one! This is also the recommend approach from the php manual: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php. +1 (and -1 the accepted answer)

Comment: Yep - I did catch that (couldn't remember the (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) syntax off the top of my head when I pulled together the script) but that's absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($file, $ignore, TRUE)) { break; }
```

Surely that should be `continue` not `break`?